# how to save indexpaths temporarily in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In filter selection view controller i will select the brands and then when i press apply it will pop to another screen and if the user to come back again to same page the previously selected should have check mark and that should save temporarily until the user leaves from filter page to list page

```
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
                    self.products = jsonObj.map{ Product(dict: $0) }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filterSelectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterSelectionCell
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        tableDetails.isHidden = false
        let product = products[indexPath.row]
        cell.brandProductName.text = product.name
        cell.accessoryType = product.selected ? .checkmark : .none
        if namesArray.count != 0 {
            for name in namesArray{
                if product.name.contains(name){
                        print(product.name)
                    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                    }
                    else {
                        cell.accessoryType = .none
                    }
                }
                }
        return cell
    }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let selected = products[indexPath.row].selected
      products[indexPath.row].selected = !selected
      tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
      let selectedItems = products.filter{ $0.selected }
      let selectedNames = products.filter{ $0.selected }.map{ $0.name }
      let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
      selectedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath as NSIndexPath)

    }
struct Product {
    let name : String
    let value : String
    let img : String
    let id : Int

    var selected = false

    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        self.name = dict["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.value = dict["value"] as? String ?? ""
        self.img = dict["img"] as? String ?? ""
        self.id = dict["id"] as? Int ?? 0
    }
}
```

[image: here is the image for filter page]

[image: here is the image for list page]

[image: here is the image for filter selection page]

Comment: Save their ids instead of indexpaths.

Comment: Use delegate for that when user click on `Apply button`.

Comment: and pass the ids to `Home screen`.

Comment: how to get id for particular product  ? @AmirKhan

Comment: How did you filter before such as "Mobiles", "Watches" and where did the list come from.

Comment: As explained in my answer to your previous question you don't need to save any temporary data at all. Everything is stored in the model. Your design cannot work, for example the loop in `cellForRow` is nonsense. Please learn how the model-view-controller pattern works.

Comment: then how to get back the data which stored previously ? @vadian